# Cannot receive emails from China

Tags: email, godaddy

We've just transferred a domain to GoDaddy and parked it.  Then bought an email plan for it and got them working ok.  Problem is we can receive most emails but whenever somebody from China emails us, the email bounces with "domain not recognized" or "unknown recipient" even though they are correct.  I have double checked the mx records and they are correct.  It has been 6 days since the mx update and it should have fully propagated before now.

We do a lot of business with China and the emails are vital.  Does anyone have any clue as to why China cannot email us?  Our domain is coriumsolutions.com.

Answer (score 1):

The sending user needs to have an SMTP gateway that recognizes the DNS MX records for your godady email.  Either the DNS provider that the china smtp gateway uses is slow to update or your records have not been approved by the great firewall of china.  China doesn't exactly forward all its DNS requests to the root DNS so there is some bit of disconnect when it comes to new domains.  If you can, see if one of your customers can ping your domain name and resolve to an ip.  If so you can also try using nslookup to see if your mx records are registered to your domain (again from the user side).  It would look like this from the cmd prompt:

```
nslookup
>set q=mx
>yourdomain.com
>here you should see your mx records
```

Comment: Thanks for tips.  Will try that if I can get through to a customer by other means.  Correction - that implies I cannot email them which is untrue.

Comment: +1, It's likely something to do with "the great firewall of china"

Comment: You emailing them is a whole different issue as your dns provider and theirs are two different entities and would not (but should) have the same records.